# JTable Connected with SQL cant see result in eclipse

Tags: java, swing

So here is my problem all thing's work fine i just cant see the result (i tried a System.out.print("done") in the showing method and everything worked fine just the table dont show me the result any help and thanks here is my codes 
i think i have problem with the table do i need to change something on it ?
PS: the method Adding is working so the problem is with table and other method maybe!

```
   public class Window extends JPanel{



       JButton Reload = new JButton("Realod");

       JButton Valider = new JButton("ADD");

       Label label  = new Label("Item : ");

       JTextField TFname = new JTextField();

       JTable table = new JTable();

       private Connection con=null;

       private PreparedStatement pst = null;

       public Window() throws SQLException {


           this.setLayout(null);

           this.add(table);

           this.add(Valider);

           this.add(label);

           this.add(TFname);

           this.add(Reload);

           label.setBounds(10,10,80,20);

           TFname.setBounds(100, 10, 80,30);

           Valider.setBounds(100, 40, 80,30);

           Reload.setBounds(160,150, 80,30);

           label.setFont(new Font("ARIAL",2,26));

           table.setBounds(50,190,300,250);

           con = Driver.connect();

           Adding();

           Showing();
}

private void Adding() throws SQLException {
    Valider.addActionListener(S->{
    if(!TFname.getText().isEmpty()) {
        String requette = "insert into Test(Nom)Values(?)";
        String Name = TFname.getText();
        try {
            pst=con.prepareStatement(requette);
            pst.setString(1, Name);
            int i = pst.executeUpdate();
            if(i==1) {
                System.out.println("ADDIND IS DONE");
            }else {
                System.out.println("Error in ADDING");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                pst.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 

        }else {
            System.out.println("ALL FIELD MUST BE FIELED");
    }


    });
}
public ArrayList<User>userList() throws SQLException{
    ArrayList<User>userList = new ArrayList<>();
    String query="Select * from Test";
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    User user;
    while(rs.next()) {
        user=new User(rs.getString("Nom"));
        userList.add(user);
    }
    return userList;
}
public void Showing() throws SQLException {
    Reload.addActionListener(e->{
    ArrayList<User> list;
    try {
        list = userList();

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    Object[] row = new Object[1];
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
        row[0]=list.get(i).getName();
        model.addRow(row);
```

Comment: `this.setLayout(null);` isn't going to help your course and a `JTable` really should be wrapped in a `JScrollPane`. Creating the `row` outside of the `for-loop` is also no a great idea, each row should be a unique instance

Comment: as i said everything worked just the table dont show the result but everything work fine (populating the table , checking the database info,getting them and putting them in ),just the table isn't showing them

Comment: Since I can't test your code - don't have a database, I can only "guess" at the cause of your problems, which, based on the available, there are a few "possible" things which aren't going to help your cause.  I would put some debug code in your `userList` and verify that the `userList` is actually getting populated and is returning a result - you're also leave the database resource dangling, again, something which isn't going to help you in the long run.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Stop, go read [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).  In fact, while you're at it, go read [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) as well.  SO is not a replacement for good tutorials, documentation and research.

Your "basic" problem comes down to the fact that the `JTable` hasn't been configured to actually show anything (columns that is).

So adding something like...

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Name"}, 0);
table.setModel(model);
```

to your constructor would solve your "immediate" issue

`this.setLayout(null);` isn't going to help you, it's going to make your life infinitely harder.  Learn to make use of the layout managers, it's time worth spent.

You should also be closing your database resources, this is where [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is so powerful

```
try (Statement st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query)) {
    User user;
    while (rs.next()) {
        user = new User(rs.getString("Nom"));
        userList.add(user);
    }
}
```

You're also mixing Swing and AWT components, this is going to generate a massive headache as you UI becomes more complex.